# How to deserialise a JSON multidimensional array with dimensions encoded in the keys

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, multidimensional-array

I'm working with a JSON API (no I can't change it!) that encodes a calendar schedule in the following format.

```
{  
    "values":
    {  
        "schedule[monday][0][time]":"06:30",  
        "schedule[monday][0][active]":false,  
        "schedule[monday][1][time]":"09:00",  
        "schedule[monday][1][active]":true,  
        "schedule[monday][2][time]":"16:30",  
        "schedule[monday][2][active]":true,  
        "schedule[tuesday][0][time]":"06:30",  
        "schedule[tuesday][0][active]":false,  
        "schedule[tuesday][1][time]":"09:00",  
        "schedule[tuesday][1][active]":true
    }
}
```

You can see they have essentially encoded the dimensions of the array (consisting of Day of Week, index of schedule and information about that index) into the *key* instead of nesting. I've been trying to deserialise into a typed collection such as (attributes removed for brevity):

```
    public class Foo
    {
        public Dictionary<DayOfWeek, List<Active>> Schedule{ get; set; }
    }

    public class Active
    {
        public DateTime Time { get; set; };
        public bool IsActive { get; set; };
    }
```

But for the purposes of getting it working I'd happily take either something simpler like `Dictionary<DayOfWeek, List<Tuple<DateTime,Bool>>>` or even an untyped multidimensional `object[]` where I can convert it into something more sensible but I do need to be able to serialise it back.

I've been trying to use Json.Net's JsonCreationConverter but it really doesn't seem geared to do this kind of conversion. Is there a better Json.Net (or other) API to use or some trick I've missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON.net has special processing for dictionaries, as is described here: [Serializing Collections](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializingCollections.htm).  Thus, if you're just looking to get the JSON into memory, you can read it as a `Dictionary<string, object>` without the need for any converter:

```
class Foo
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> values { get; set; }
}
```

And then later:

```
        var schedule = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(jsonString);

        Debug.Assert(schedule.values.Count == 10); // No assert
        Debug.Assert(object.Equals(schedule.values["schedule[tuesday][1][time]"], "09:00")); // No assert
        Debug.Assert(schedule.values["schedule[tuesday][1][time]"].GetType() == typeof(string)); // No assert
        Debug.Assert(object.Equals(schedule.values["schedule[tuesday][1][active]"], true)); // No assert
        Debug.Assert(schedule.values["schedule[tuesday][1][active]"].GetType() == typeof(bool)); // No assert
```

This will also re-serialize the data with the correct format.

Of course, you still will have to actually parse the dictionary keys and values, but at least you've got them in memory.

By the way, the last line of your JSON is wrong; the quote after the `true"` should not be there:

```
    "schedule[tuesday][1][active]":true
```

**Update**

If you're wedded to your `Dictionary<DayOfWeek, List<Active>> Schedule` representation, you can use a `JsonConverter` to convert between your dictionary and a `Dictionary<string, object>` intermediate representation for serialization/deserialization, like so:

```
public class Active
{
    public bool IsActive { get; set; } // Cannot have the same name as the class
    public TimeSpan TimeOfDay { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
class Foo
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ScheduleDictionaryConverter))]
    [DataMember(Name = "values")]
    public Dictionary<DayOfWeek, List<Active>> Schedule { get; set; }
}

public class ScheduleDictionaryConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Dictionary<DayOfWeek, List<Active>>);
    }

    static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> GetDictionaryValues(Active item, DayOfWeek day, int index)
    {
        string key1 = string.Format("schedule[{0}][{1}][{2}]", day, index, "time");
        yield return new KeyValuePair<string, object>(key1, item.TimeOfDay.ToString());
        string key2 = string.Format("schedule[{0}][{1}][{2}]", day, index, "active");
        yield return new KeyValuePair<string, object>(key2, item.IsActive);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);

        var value = token.ToObject<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        if (value == null)
            return null;
        var dict = new Dictionary<DayOfWeek, List<Active>>();
        foreach (var pair in value)
        {
            var key = pair.Key;
            var keys = key.Split(new char[] { '[', ']' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            if (keys.Length != 4)
                continue; // Error
            if (keys[0] != "schedule")
                continue;
            DayOfWeek day;
            if (!Enum.TryParse(keys[1], out day))
                continue;
            int index;
            if (!int.TryParse(keys[2], NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out index))
                continue;
            if (keys[3] == "time")
            {
                if (pair.Value is string)
                {
                    TimeSpan span;
                    if (TimeSpan.TryParse((string)pair.Value, out span))
                        dict.DemandScheduleItem(day, index).TimeOfDay = span;
                }
            }
            else if (keys[3] == "active")
            {
                if (pair.Value is bool)
                    dict.DemandScheduleItem(day, index).IsActive = (bool)pair.Value;
            }
        }
        return dict;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return;
        var Schedule = (Dictionary<DayOfWeek, List<Active>>)value;
        var dict =
            Schedule
            .SelectMany(pair => pair.Value.Select((item, i) => new { Item = item, Day = pair.Key, Index = i }))
            .SelectMany(x => GetDictionaryValues(x.Item, x.Day, x.Index))
            .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
        serializer.Serialize(writer, dict);
    }
}

public static class ScheduleExtensions
{
    public static void Resize<T>(this List<T> list, int count)
    {
        if (list == null || count < 0)
            throw new ArgumentException();
        int oldCount = list.Count;
        if (count > oldCount)
        {
            list.Capacity = count;
            for (int i = oldCount; i < count; i++)
                list.Add(default(T));
        }
        else if (count < oldCount)
        {
            for (int i = oldCount - 1; i >= count; i--)
                list.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }

    public static void EnsureCount<T>(this List<T> list, int count)
    {
        if (list == null || count < 0)
            throw new ArgumentException();
        if (count > list.Count)
            list.Resize(count);
    }

    public static Active DemandScheduleItem(this IDictionary<DayOfWeek, List<Active>> schedule, DayOfWeek day, int index)
    {
        List<Active> inner;

        if (!schedule.TryGetValue(day, out inner))
            schedule[day] = inner = new List<Active>();
        inner.EnsureCount(index+1);
        if (inner[index] == null)
            inner[index] = new Active();
        return inner[index];
    }
}
```

Comment: So good news this essentially worked. I'm glad you did the update as I'd got as far as the Dictionary<string,object> but didn't consider that deserialised. Also really like the use of yield to flatten the structure into the keys. I had to make a few tweaks to get this running that I'll list for others: firstly this didn't deal with the collection being nested in "values" which was an easy fix. Next I made the Enum parsing case invariant (and ToLower the serialisation). I also had to apply a format string to the serialisation of the timespan (@"hh\:mm"). Ultimately a pretty complete solution!